# how position the pieces of picture to diffrent places

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

i just combine three logo picture as png format becouse of reduce the times of requesting to server and improve the speed.

i can position the entire picutre with absolute attribute for example

```
div.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

[enter image description here][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGKVu.png
but what i want is how make one picture to 3 pieces and set each of them to special area 
what code i should write?

Comment: That combine image is nothing but the sprite sheet. You can refer https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ article to play around. I hope it will offer you solution to your query.

Comment: @VipulPatil tnx for attention

Comment: Whichever answer/comment resolved your query, please accept/upvote that answer/comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for image sprite

`#icon{
    left: 63px; //define part of image
    width: 43px;
    background: url('picture.gif') 0 0; // defines the background image and position(image, left, top) 
}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this.

html

```
<div class="logos">
  <div class="img1"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff"/></div>
  <div class="img2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff"/></div>
  <div class="img3"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff"/></div>
<div>
```

CSS

```
.logos>div{
  position:absolute;
}

.logos>div.img1{
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
.logos>div.img2{
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
.logos>div.img3{
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```